# Change scancode in registry - 'arrow up' to 'shift rigtht'

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-registry, remapping

I have a problem with my Lenovo v510 keyboard (Windows 10).

[image: Keyboard Lenovo V510]

My <kbd>up</kbd> <kbd>arrow</kbd> is next to my <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>right</kbd> button and every time I have to use uppercase letters, I hit the wrong key.

Now I try to change the scancode map for the 'arrow up' button. This button should have the function from 'shift right'.

I used the following with WIN+R to change the scancode map but it doesn't work.

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout /v ScancodeMap /t REG_BINARY /d 00000000000000000200000048E0360000000000
```

or

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout" /v "Scancode Map" /t REG_BINARY /d 00000000000000000200000048E0360000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the registry manually, you may use
[PowerToys](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/microsoft-powertoys/XP89DCGQ3K6VLD),
as follows:

- Run "Keyboard Manager" from its sidebar
- Click `+`
- Select the key to remap in the "Key:" column by either clicking
  the "Type" button and pressing the key on your keyboard,
  or by selecting it from the list in the drop-down menu
- Select the key in the "To:" column in the same way
- Click OK.

For more information with screenshots see the article
[How to Remap Any Key or Shortcut on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/710290/how-to-remap-any-key-or-shortcut-on-windows-10/).

---

As the Keyboard Manager of PowerToys does not operate via the
registry, a product that does that is
[SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys):

> SharpKeys is a utility that manages a Registry key that allows Windows to remap one key to any other key. Included in the application is a list of common keyboard keys and a Type Key feature to automatically recognize most keyboard keys.

Comment: Thank you, that works fine but is there any other solution in bios or registry? I had to reset the laptop and before that the problem was solved differently. First I thought PowerToys modify the registry but I have to run the app in the background.

Comment: Sorry, I thought so too by its description. I added another open-source utility that does manage this registry key.

Comment: @harrymc Not within 24 hours please. Other users may come in with different or even better answers.